# Android Paint.setBlendMode Crash

Tags: java, android, androidx

I'm using paint to draw highlight boxes on top of some text using a canvas. I need to set the paint blendmode to multiply.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
paint.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);
```

This however, causes a crash:
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/BlendMode;**

It doesn't happen on my Oneplus 6T where it works perfectly. On my LG V10 however, this crash happens.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
    implementation 'com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.1'
    implementation files('libs\\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: Try to rebuild your project and check if it's working. Please post the build.gradle file too.

Comment: A rebuild did not help unfortunately. The build.gradle is posted.

Answer (score 1):

***Solved**

So apparently setBlendMode requires was introduced in API-level 29 and this is the reason it didn't work on my V10 which is running Android 7. The solution that i discovered was to simply use the older Paint.setXfermode with PorterDuff Multiply mode.

```
Paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode